# Jar file doesn't work on the web server

Tags: java, php, jar, webserver, exec

I have an Jar file that is working perfectly fine on my Mac using console:

```
 MacBook-Pro-Pavel:PDFparser pavelpigalev$ java -jar PDFparser.jar
 Usage: java PDFparser <input-pdf> -p1 <password> -c1 -i0 -s1
    -p1 : PDF password
    -c1 : write JSON to console
    -i0 : don't extract images
    -s1 : take page screenshots [WARNING: currently in beta]
 MacBook-Pro-Pavel:PDFparser pavelpigalev$ java -jar PDFparser.jar f5.pdf
 MacBook-Pro-Pavel:PDFparser pavelpigalev$
```

It creates a folder and puts out images that I need in that folder.

But if I use it on the web server (also using console) it gives me this error:

```
 [root@somesite.com pdfparser]$ ls
ffive.pdf  lib  PDFparser.jar  README.TXT
[root@somesite.com pdfparser]$ java -jar "PDFparser.jar"
Usage: java PDFparser <input-pdf> -p1 <password> -c1 -i0 -s1
    -p1 : PDF password
    -c1 : write JSON to console
    -i0 : don't extract images
    -s1 : take page screenshots [WARNING: currently in beta]
[root@somesite.com pdfparser]$ java -jar "PDFparser.jar" ffive.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.vecmath.Vector2d not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:PDFparser.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.reflect.Field.getType(libgcj.so.10)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.excludeField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:56)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:111)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:52)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:578)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:520)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:500)
   at pdfparser.PDFparser.main(PDFparser.java:163)
```

I didn't make this Jar file, I don't really know much about Java. I work with PHP and I really need this program working well on server. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place vechmath `.jar` in your class path

Or - Add your supporting `.jar`s to the classpath

`export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/vecmath.jar`

Or - Supply at the Runtime

```
java -cp vecmath-xxx.jar -jar Yourjar.jar
```

Importance of [Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Can you explain again what should I do? What is class path? And what is vechmath? I'm sorry if it is something that everybody supposed to know

Comment: classpath is environment variable where java looks for dependencies (libraries) more [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-classpath-unix/)

Comment: like the way i added in answer, but you have to find the correct path of your `vechmath-x-x-x.jar`

Comment: You know I don't really get it.. I am a dumb person in this.. Where should I write it? And how do I find this vechmath-x-x-x.jar? Should I just download it and put to the same folder? Can you write steps of what I should do to make this program work please?

Comment: sorry @PigalevPavel `x-x-x` i mean whatever the version of jar file you may have for example if you have 1.3.1 it'll be `vechmath-1.3.1.jar`

Comment: I understood that...I don't know where can I find it and where should I put it and a lot of other things... Could you please write steps of what I suppose to do to make this .jar file work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23632/discussion-between-techexchange-and-pigalev-pavel)

Comment: Thanks for everything... I've made it like this: I've opened MANIFEST.MF file and added the path to vecmath.jar to the line 'Class-path:'. And I also added the vecmath.jar file to the folder where my PDFparser.jar was. I think you ment that at first. I just didn't get it then. I also updated Java version on the server and now it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the same JVM that the one in your macbook. You're using GNU JVM as seen in `not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader`

Try a `java -version` to confim that and then change your JVM

Answer (score 0):

Try to find vecmath-1.3.1.jar file on you Mac and place it in the same dir as PDFparser.jar is located. Try to run. If no success then try to run as follow:

```
 java -cp vecmath-1.3.1.jar -jar "PDFparser.jar"
```